# Python mock class instance variable

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using Python's `mock` library. I know how to mock a class instance method by following the [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130521231218/https://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/getting-started.html#mocking-classes):

```
>>> def some_function():
...     instance = module.Foo()
...     return instance.method()
...
>>> with patch('module.Foo') as mock:
...     instance = mock.return_value
...     instance.method.return_value = 'the result'
...     result = some_function()
...     assert result == 'the result'
```

However, tried to mock a class instance variable but doesn't work (`instance.labels` in the following example):

```
>>> with patch('module.Foo') as mock:
...     instance = mock.return_value
...     instance.method.return_value = 'the result'
...     instance.labels = [1, 1, 2, 2]
...     result = some_function()
...     assert result == 'the result'
```

Basically I want `instance.labels` under `some_function` get the value I want. Any hints?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This version of `some_function()` prints mocked `labels` property:

```
def some_function():
    instance = module.Foo()
    print instance.labels
    return instance.method()
```

My `module.py`:

```
class Foo(object):

    labels = [5, 6, 7]

    def method(self):
        return 'some'
```

Patching is the same as yours:

```
with patch('module.Foo') as mock:
    instance = mock.return_value
    instance.method.return_value = 'the result'
    instance.labels = [1,2,3,4,5]
    result = some_function()
    assert result == 'the result
```

Full console session:

```
>>> from mock import patch
>>> import module
>>> 
>>> def some_function():
...     instance = module.Foo()
...     print instance.labels
...     return instance.method()
... 
>>> some_function()
[5, 6, 7]
'some'
>>> 
>>> with patch('module.Foo') as mock:
...     instance = mock.return_value
...     instance.method.return_value = 'the result'
...     instance.labels = [1,2,3,4,5]
...     result = some_function()
...     assert result == 'the result'
...     
... 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

For me your code *is* working.

Comment: It doesn't work. I got the same result as `instance.labels = [1, 1, 2, 2]`, which is this mocked variable didn't get used by `some_function`. In the documentation it's mocking out method instead of variable.

Comment: Updated my answer. Now I'm lost because your code is working.

Comment: In my code, `labels` only appears after calling some function. And that function is called within the function I want to test. Maybe that's the reason. I end up mock out the initialization of the class so that it returns the mock object with behavior i want.

Comment: I want to raise an exception when I'm dule.Foo instance is created. So I tried both mock.side_effect and mock.return_value. Both didn't work. Why?

Comment: That's a different question and there is no code we can look at, but I guess this question is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305406/mocking-a-function-to-raise-an-exception-to-test-an-except-block