# Trouble mocking the return value of python-gitlab method

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-gitlab

I am trying to mock the return value of the following method

```
import gitlab
from unittest.mock import patch

def get_all_iters():
   gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url='test_url', private_token)
   result = gl.groups.get(1).iterations.list() # trying to mock the result of this method call

   return result

@patch('gitlab.Gitlab')
@patch('gitlab.v4.objects.GroupManager')
@patch('gitlab.mixins.ListMixin.list')
def test_my_code(mockGitlab, mockGroup, mockList):
   mockList.return_value = ['a', 'b']
   result = get_all_iters()
   print(result)
```

Although I have tried to mock the return value of the method call, it is still returning the mock object instead of what I tried to mock

```
<MagicMock name='Gitlab().groups.get().iterations.list()' id='1688988996464'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the following solution for your problem (I have tested it in my system):

```
import gitlab
from unittest.mock import patch

def get_all_iters():
   #gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url='test_url', private_token) # <--- Remove your instruction and substitute with the following
   gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url='test_url', private_token='test_token_value')  # <--- HERE I have set the value for the argument private_token
   result = gl.groups.get(1).iterations.list() # trying to mock the result of this method call
   return result

# here it remains a patch() instruction, other mocks are managed by
# context manager inserted into the body of the test method
@patch('gitlab.Gitlab')
def test_my_code(mockGitlab):
    instance_gl = mockGitlab.return_value
    with patch.object(instance_gl, 'groups') as mock_groups:
        with patch.object(mock_groups, 'get') as mock_get:
            instance_get = mock_get.return_value
            with patch.object(instance_get, 'iterations') as mock_iterations:
                with patch.object(mock_iterations, 'list') as mockList:
                    # -------> FINALLY here are your test instructions
                    mockList.return_value = ['a', 'b']
                    result = get_all_iters()
                    print(result)

test_my_code()
```

The execution of the test method on my system is:

```
['a', 'b']
```

that is the print of the desired value for `result` set by your instruction `mockList.return_value = ['a', 'b']`.

### Some notes about the test

Note the instructions:

```
instance_gl = mockGitlab.return_value
instance_get = mock_get.return_value
```

By those instructions we can get the right Mock objects.

Furthermore note the presence of the instructions `patch.object()` and not only of the `patch()` instruction.

There is probably a simpler solution, but since you desire to mock the `list` get by the complex instruction:

```
gl.groups.get(1).iterations.list()
```

I have been able to find only this way!

---

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731477/python-mock-class-instance-variable) is old but useful to add more details to my explanation.